# asp.net mvc 5 routing different position of action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

I'm making an app for myself and i have a problem in routing.

asp.net mvc routeConfig.cs default is below :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

and i want a redirect link like book/1/edit or book/1/history.

If i edit this code lines below is working

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default2",
    url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    constraint : new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

but at this time if i goes the link "book/add", website redirect me to the book list action so that means the code i added after didn't work.

what should i do now?

Comment: MVC 5 introduced `AttributeRouting`. Why don't you try that? It will make things much easier. Refer
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: What do you mean _redirects to book list_? What is book list? And do you have a method in `BookController` named `Add()`? You have also said _f i edit this code_ - I assume you mean that you have added the `Default2` route and its before the `Default` route?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have a controller called BookController and some actions like Add(), List(), Edit(), History(). i have added Default2 route before default

Comment: @AnkitVijay i looked the attribute routing but i want to make it default for all controllers.

i want to make a default route for all controller instead of make a special route for each one like book/{id}/{action} or user/{id}/{action} or author/{id}/{action}

do you understand me ?

Comment: Then `../Book/Add` would go to the `Add()` method of `BookController` (unless you have other matching routes before the Default). What do you mean redirects to book list?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i mean to book list book is controller and list is action name. ok. 

book/add link goes to list action instead of add action. why ?

Comment: It wont. I can only assume you have typos in your code, or its due to code you have not shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Remove default route to disable default convention

Make Your Default2 as your Default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    constraint : new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Comment: i did but not work. when i goes to book/add link, site redirect me list action. why ?